# Data binding with MongoDB and python and pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, data-binding, pymongo

I'm an experienced applications programmer, but I'm not really a database person.

Recently, I've started working on a project which involves MongoDB and Python. I'm using pymongo as my interface.

It's all going fine, but I'd like to get a tighter integration between the database and what's going on in my code.

In an earlier project using MySQL and C#, I could 'bind' data structures in the program to data in the DB, so when I changed data in my structure, it was immediately changed in the DB (and also reflected in the UI which was bound to the DB).

With PyMongo/MongoDB, I can't see a way to do that - I read a JSON/BSON structure out of the DB, modify it, then write the whole structure back, in 3 operations. In C#, I did one bind at the start, then could read and modify the DB contents to my heart's content, with changes being visible in the DB in real time, then shut down the binding when I was done.

Is there a way to do something similar in MongoDB? I'd like to stick to pymongo, but I'll switch if I need to.

thanks